# PDOStatement fetch/fetchAll parameter array

Tags: php, pdo

[The `PDOStatement` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) has a method

```
public bool execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )
```

which takes an associative array of parameters to bind to the parameterized statement before execution.

Where is the equivalent of this for `fetch` or `fetchAll`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the fetch and fetchall and execute are related. The execute is needed THEN you have the option to fetch or fetchAll if needed.

Comment: @azngunit81 Ah. So `fetch` and `fetchAll` implicitly call `execute` if it hasn't already been called. Confusing. Thanks.

Comment: No no. you need to do it AFTER an execute. What you get from fetchall is the entire payload of your result. Fetch gets you one row which you then need to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that my comment is not enough - here is a complete answer that will compliment the user "Your Common Sense" who started the answer.

As mentioned - fetch/fetchall compliments the execute (you need to use it AFTER execute if you are doing a SELECT statement)

The difference is that fetch retrieve ONE row, where as fetchAll will get you the entire payload. If the payload is low - you can fetch it and then iterate yourself without going through the fetching part again. As an example:

```
  $sql = 'SELECT hand, won, bet FROM mynumbers ORDER BY bet';
  try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
    do {
      $data = $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
      print $data;
    } while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_PRIOR));
    $stmt = null;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

you can reflect the fetch in this case and do `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and then `foreach($rows as $row)` where `$row` is each row

Answer (score 1):

These functions have different purpose.

`execute()` is for the query execution and `fetchAll()` for the result fetching. Although one indeed can make them interchangeable, but PDO authors decided not to do so. And it's indeed an inconsistency of this otherwise great library.

So, you are supposed to call them in turn. And you cannot even use method chaining, as execute returns boolean instead of self. However, with slight tweaking, it's quite possible. I've made it in my [PDO helper library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper), to make it able to call like this:

```
$data = DB::prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=?")->execute([$id])->fetchAll();
```

Which I find quite acceptable tradeoff between usability and compatibility